# Android missing resource exception even though it's in the APK

Tags: android, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I'm running into some problems trying create a library that shows a DialogFragment with a WebView inside. This project is setup so it can be used as a Titanium Module for a Appcelerator app.

When I use my library in a native Android sample app, it works fine. But when I use it in my Titanium app, I get the following error:

```
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142): Process: be.iminds.livinglabs.wappr, PID: 25142
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f020000
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2821)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2776)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1165)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at be.iminds.mupets_client_android.esm.EsmDialogFragment.onCreateView(EsmDialogFragment.java:61)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Corrupt XML binary file
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:485)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2803)
06-14 11:58:57.287: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    ... 18 more
```

So I naturally thought there was some missing dependencies or maybe the file in question wasn't compiled in the app. However, when I explode the compiled APK, the file mentioned is exactly in the location the system says it can't find it.

Can somebody help me? I've been stuck on this issue for weeks now.

Thx!

EDIT:

Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

def GROUP_ID = 'be.iminds.mupets'
def ARTIFACT_ID = 'mupets'
def VERSION = "1.0.2"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        encoding = 'UTF-8'
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        warning 'InvalidPackage'
        abortOnError false
    }
}

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
        return; // Skip debug builds.
    }
    task("javadoc${variant.name.capitalize()}", type: Javadoc) {
        description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
        source = variant.javaCompile.source

        // Add all of your dependencies and android jars to the classpath
        classpath += files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files)
        classpath += files(android.getBootClasspath())
        exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
        exclude '**/R.java'

        options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/")
        options.linksOffline("http://d.android.com/reference", "${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference")
        options.charSet("utf-8")
    }

    task("bundleJavadoc${variant.name.capitalize()}", type: Jar) {
        description "Bundles Javadoc into zip for $variant.name."
        classifier = "javadoc"
        from tasks["javadoc${variant.name.capitalize()}"]
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.cookpad.puree:puree:4.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
}

task androidJar(type: Jar) {
    from 'build/intermediates/classes/release'
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

task androidJavadocJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from 'build/docs/javadoc'
}

artifacts {
    archives androidJar
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocJar
}

task deployJavadoc(type: Exec) {
    workingDir '../'
    executable "./deploy_javadoc.sh"
    args VERSION
}
```

Comment: A clean and re-build usually does the trick

Comment: @Ventis can you tell me what is your Android Gradle plugin ?

Comment: @Ironman my Gradle plugin is 2.1.2.

Comment: @insomniac I can clean and rebuild as much as I want, it doesn't fix it :)

Comment: @Ventis post `build.gradle` file here.

Comment: @Ironman I edited it in my post. :)